# How to find out which third party library versions are included in a WebSphere release

Tags: websphere, java

I wonder if there is any IBM website that lists the versions of the third party libraries that are included in a WAS release.

This would help me a lot, because I try to define a maven dependency management for the IBM WAS libraries so that I can debug through the code.

For example: Which javax.el version is included in WAS 8.0.0.1?

If IBM doesn't provide such a list we schould use this Question to create the list by ourselves.
What do you think?